# Beautiful soup Crawl and extracting text from in between <br>

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

My html code looks like this:

```
 <br><a href="/drink12xy569.html">Alien Suicide</a>
 <br><a href="/drink792.html">All Jacked Up</a>
 <br><a href="/drink3805.html">All Night Hunter</a>
 <br><a href="/drink796.html">Alley Shooter</a>
 <br><a href="/drink10013.html">Alligator Sperm</a>
 <br><a href="/drink804.html">Almond Delight</a>
 <br><a href="/drink11135.html">Almond Gravy</a>
 <br><a href="/drink7519.html">Almond Joy #2</a>
 <br><a href="/drinks1r2563.html">Almond Kiss</a>
 <br><a href="/drink12xy578.html">Amaretto Pie</a>
 <br><a href="/drink11144.html">Amaretto Sourball</a>
 <br><a href="/drinkp15q144.html">Ambuco Cinnamon Shooter</a>
 <br><a href="/drink835.html">Amenie Mama</a>
 <br><a href="/drink7521.html">American Death</a>
```

I need help to extract the titles in between the `<br>` and then print it out. I then need help writing this information along with the other information I've pulled into a text document that I can search using the gui interface. I have the separate codes and can put them all together in the end I just need concept help.

My beautiful soup crawl looks like this:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url=[]
for i in range(28):
    url="http://www.drinksmixer.com/cat/3/"
    page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.drinksmixer.com/cat/3/")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
    links=soup.find_all('a')

for link in links:
    if "drink" in link ['href']:
        print link['href']
        print "****\n\n"
        url="http://drinksmixer.com"+link['href']
        page1=urllib2.urlopen(url)
        soup1=BeautifulSoup(page1.read())
        divs=soup1.find('div', {"class":"ingredients"})
        print divs.text.encode("utf-8")
```

My gui interface looks like this:

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *

def show_entry_fields():
   print("Shot Name: %s" % (e1.get()))

master = Tk()
Label(master, text="Shot Name").grid(row=0)

e1 = Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

Button(master, text='Search', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop( )
```

I just need help implementing the search in the information I've extracted too.

Comment: It might be easier to just iterate through all of the drink pages wrapping it in a `try: except:` starting at 1 (`http://www.drinksmixer.com/drink####.html`)

Answer (score 2):

Designing UI isn't too easy. Your code was almost ok. I separated it into functions and added basic search that You asked for.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *

e1 = None
links = []

def get_drinks():
    global links
    for i in range(28):
        url="http://www.drinksmixer.com/cat/3/" + i
        page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
        links.append(soup.find_all('a'))

def get_recipe(drink_name):
    print drink_name
    for link in links:
        if "drink" in link ['href'] and drink_name in link.contents:
            #print link['href']
            print "****\n\n"
            url="http://drinksmixer.com"+link['href']
            page1=urllib2.urlopen(url)
            soup1=BeautifulSoup(page1.read())
            divs=soup1.find('div', {"class":"ingredients"})
            recipe = divs.text.encode("utf-8")
            return recipe

def show_entry_fields():
    drink_name = e1.get()
    print("Shot Name: %s" % drink_name)
    recipe = get_recipe(drink_name)
    print recipe # or better yet, popup
    # tkMessageBox.showinfo(drink_name, recipe)

def main():
    global e1
    master = Tk()
    Label(master, text="Shot Name").grid(row=0)
    e1 = Entry(master)
    e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    Button(master, text='Search', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
    mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_drinks()
    main()
```

Comment: how would i get the response to pop up in the gui instead of in python?

Comment: Uncomment line `tkMessageBox.showinfo(drink_name, recipe)` this should do.

Comment: @robersam does it work? If so then you might want to close/accept this answer.

Comment: it does but i still haven't gotten help on how to look the different pages of the site.

Comment: There, I've edited answer to show one possibility to iterate through many pages. In case there are lot's of pages You should check Python's generators, to allow loading more pages/drinks in background while Your app is running.